# Filtering JQuery Autoncomplete Results in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, autocomplete

I'm trying to have my PHP script that converts a CSV table to a JSON array for my JQuery autocomplete field filter results based on the user's input. This is the PHP code I have so far:

```
<?php
$file="partstable.csv";
$csv= file_get_contents($file);
$input = $_GET["term"];
$lines = explode("\n", $csv);
$head = str_getcsv(array_shift($lines));
$array = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $array[] = array_combine($head, str_getcsv($line));
}
$result = array_filter($array, function ($item) use ($input) {
    if (stripos($item, $input) !== false) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
print json_encode($result);
?>
```

**CSV:**

```
label,Number,PartDesc,Source
"First Part",10002345,This is a description of the part,1
"Second Part",10006789,This is also a part description,1
.....
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function() {      
    $('#partName').autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: "readcsv.php",
        select: function ( event, ui ) {
        $("#partNumber").text(ui.item.Number);
        $("#partDesc").text(ui.item.PartDesc);
            if (ui.item.Source == 1 && document.getElementById('radio1').checked) {
                $("#partSource").html("<div class='ui-widget'><div class = 'ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all' style='margin=top:5px;'><p><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert' style='float: left; margin-right: 6px;'></span> TEXT</p></div></div>");
            }
            else if (ui.item.Source == 1 && document.getElementById('radio2').checked) {
                $("#partSource").html("<div class='ui-widget'><div class = 'ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all' style='margin=top:5px;'><p><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert' style='float: left; margin-right: 6px;'></span> TEXT </p></div></div>");
            }
            else if (ui.item.Source == 2) {
                $("#partSource").html("<div class='ui-widget'><div class = 'ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all' style='margin=top:5px;'><p><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert' style='float: left; margin-right: 6px;'></span> TEXT</p></div></div>");
            }
            else {
                $("#partSource").html("<div class='ui-widget'><div class = 'ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all' style='margin=top:5px;'><p><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert' style='float: left; margin-right: 6px;'></span> TEXT</p></div></div>");
            }
      }
    });
})
```

However, this still causes the AutoComplete text box to give me all labels in the array. I know my Search page is passing the search string to my PHP script properly, so the fault lies in this script somewhere. If I understand my code, it should be going through my array, line-by-line, only returning labels start contain the entered search string in `$input`, correct?

Comment: Each item of `$array` is an array itself, yet you attempt to find `$input` in this array - not within specific item of it. Are you sure there's no omissions in the code you've shown?

Comment: @raina77ow The code I posted is the entire .php file, so I'm missing a step in what the search should be doing. So I need to only search the content of the label string inside of each component array; just need to determine how to go about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Use this (I already tested it):

```
$result = array_filter($array, function ($item) use ($input) {
    foreach($item as $field){
        if(stripos($field, $input, 0) !== false) return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Using `multineedle_stripos` seems to be causing a Error 500 on my server; I'm trying to pin down if this is a issue with the server executing my script, or if it's the array filter that's causing the problem. The script was working prior to replacing `stripos` with `multineedle_stripos`

Comment: EDIT: My mistake; I needed to define multineedle_stripos in my code. That resolved the Error 500, but it's still not filtering my results...

Comment: Would you please post your own csv example to debug it better?

Comment: Added the .csv to my original post. Sorry for not adding that beforehand.

Comment: check out my new answer, as @raina77ow pointed, there was an error giving the function an array, so it was returning always something different from `(boolean)false` so ...

Comment: I've inserted the code you've suggested, though the script still returns a Null JSON array when I hard code a test value into `$input`.